# ''show Hierarchy Page'' Button gives error

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am administrator of a dynamics crm (on-premises) version 8.2.
A hierarchy rule was defined for "employee" entity.
The context seems to be set correctly, but clicking the "show Hierarchy Page" button leads to an error (attached screenshot).

["show Hierarchy Page" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2Vz8.jpg)

[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV2Fq.jpg)

In the development environment the button works properly, the error only appears in the production environment.

For other entities defined with hierarchical rules - the button works properly.
the error occurs from anywhere you can access the hierarchy page (from the views and the form), and for each employee type record. the error occurs in all browsers

I checked the definition of the hierarchy, and I transferred a solution to the production environment, which includes the relevant fields, relationships and hierarchy rules.

So far nothing has helped.

What else can lead to such an error?

Comment: Did you check the `Event Log` on the crm server? Maybe you can find detailed error there

Comment: Thanks Arsen ,
I checked the traces in the server, but found no documentation of the error.
No new trace is created when the error occurs.